# Unable to install psycopg2 2.8.6 on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am unable to install psycopg2 2.8.6 or psycopg2-binary on my Windows.
While installing I am getting below error.

PS C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\PythonUnitTestFW> pip install psycopg2-binary
Collecting psycopg2-binary
Using cached psycopg2-binary-2.8.6.tar.gz (384 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e12d1gsx\psycopg2-binary\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e12d1gsx\psycopg2-binary\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bs6x9b8l'
cwd: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e12d1gsx\psycopg2-binary
Complete output (23 lines):
running egg_info
creating C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bs6x9b8l\psycopg2_binary.egg-info
writing C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bs6x9b8l\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bs6x9b8l\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bs6x9b8l\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bs6x9b8l\psycopg2_binary.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: If you are installing for Python3 you may need to use pip3 instead of pip (depending on your config)

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully ? **... please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.**

Comment: Yes, I tried installing psycopg2-binary too. It still gives me error.